# Sending email to three email id's with intent in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I want to send email to three email id's at once if the button is clicked, via the email clients installed in the user's phone.

I am using the code below, as it is a onClickListener and Switch case:

public class ContactInfo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
Button bcall,bmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contactinfo);

    bcall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bcall);
    bmail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bmail);

    bcall.setOnClickListener(this);
    bmail.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent launch;

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.bcall:
        launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:+10000000"));
        startActivity(launch);
        break;

    case R.id.bmail:
        launch = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        launch.setType("text/plain");
        launch.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com", "web@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com"});
        launch.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "restaurant");
        launch.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent via - Android Application");
        try{
            startActivity(launch);
            }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                Toast.makeText(ContactInfo.this, "There are no Email Clients", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        break;

    }


}
```

It is working but it is not taking any given email addresses in the email id column.

Comment: Please have a look at below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like below.

```
launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
launch.setType("text/plain");
launch .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {
                "abc@gmail.com", "abc@gmail.com" });
        launch .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
```

You have to use `new String[]` array to send email to multiple people. Also change `ACTION_SENDTO` to `ACTION_SEND`...

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is not taking email id's in send row automatically

Comment: I didn't get you. What you are asking.

Comment: I am saying that if i clicked the send email button, then email apps open but there are no pre defined email id's in the sender's address textbox

Comment: I have edited the above with full code, and can you help me with this, its opening some other apps also which are not for email, like whatsapp etc. What's reason for that.

Comment: Please reply and help for it

Answer (score 0):

change

```
launch.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailid@1.com, emailid@2.com, emailid@3.com");
```

to this :

```
 launch.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{ 
 "emailid@1.com, emailid@2.com, emailid@3.com"});
```